# how to solve sqlite_prepare error

Tags: iphone, database, xcode, sqlite

I know when I use 'sqlite3_open' will opening a new database instead of my sqlite file.
so I fixed it by using 'sqlite3_open_v2'.
But now ,I still can't get my data from my file. Can anyone tell me how to result it?
very thanks!

### here is my code:

```
(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
databaseName=@"freeway.sqlite";

[databasePath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
databasePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"freeway.sqlite"];

[self checkAndCreateDatabase];
[self readDataFromDatabase];
}
```

-

```
(void)checkAndCreateDatabase
{

BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager];
success=[fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
if (success) 
{  NSLog(@"success");
return;
}
else {
    NSLog(@"fail");
    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];       
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];       
}
}
```

-

```
(void)readDataFromDatabase
sqlite3 *database;
fee = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

//if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    if (sqlite3_open_v2([databasePath  UTF8String], &database, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)       
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    char *sql = "SELECT * FROM fee";     

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql,-1,&stmt,NULL) == SQLITE_OK){
        while (sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW) {
            NSInteger pID = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
            NSString *pName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 1)];
            NSString *pName2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 2)];

            Fee_Station *temp = [[Fee_Station alloc] initwithFCID:pID F_Name:pName Fmaileage:pName2];
            [fee addObject:temp];          
    }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"%s Prepare failure '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));
    }     
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: use this   NSLog(@"error = %d",sqlite3_errcode(database)); and get error code

Comment: I guess it can't catch the file path.But I don't know how to let it get the path.

Comment: No error messages? No debugging? No indication of where it's going wrong?

Comment: error message is"no such table: fee"" I think it can't get the path,than it create a new one.Thus, in the new file must not have the table "fee". It's just my guess. I'm a beginner ,don't know how to fixed it.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",databasePath);
the result:/Users/ai_erh/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/1ACA32E4-D668-4A7A-9F42-84ED699949BD/Documents/freeway.sqlite

Answer (score 0):

your checkAndCreateDatabase database function call inside the Application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions  method,

after that

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase
{

    BOOL success;


    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success) return;
    else
        printf("NO File found");

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    //[fileManager release];
}

-(void)readDataFromDatabase
{

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"freeway.sqlite"];
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;
    sqlite3 *database;
    if(sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

        const char *sqlStatement;

        sqlStatement = "SELECT * FROM fee"; 

        sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL);

        printf("\nError===%s",sqlite3_errmsg(database));


        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {


            while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW ) 

            {

                NSString *str_field1=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 0)];

                NSString *str_field2=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 1)];

                NSString *str_field3=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

                NSString *str_field4=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 3)];


                // add str_field into array


            }

        }

        sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);


    }


    sqlite3_close(database);

}
```

Comment: hi,I tried your teaching, but still print "fail" and"Error===no such table: fee"
I'm sure that i have copy my database file into the project document.
It's seen like it can't get the file path.how can I solve it? thank you.

Comment: I added the CheckandCreateDatabase code above. use that function instead of your checkandcreatedatabase function.

Comment: Still don't get the data, the output is"Error===no such table: fee"

Comment: go like this way /Users/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications in that user project document is there your .sqlite file available or not and also check your tablename this case sensitive.

Comment: my freeway.sqlite file is available in the project document. the sqlStatement can succeed in SQLite-Manager.And table name is correct.I'm confused at this point for 3 day.I'm going crazy.

Comment: you said output is"Error===no such table: fee it means that your select query table name is not same in the sqlite table name check that

Comment: I check the table name already ,no mistake... But still thank you for a lot!